# .bashrc break, second line entered in shell eats up first line

Tags: bash

I've using a .bashrc from one of peepcode's screencast.

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi

# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ]; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
    See "man sudo_root" for details.

    EOF
    fi
    esac
fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- $1
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/bin/python /usr/share/command-not-found -- $1
                   return $?
        else
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi

. ~/bin/bash_colors.sh

#load bash aliases
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# Unbreak broken, non-colored terminal
export TERM='xterm-color'
alias ls='ls -G'
alias ll='ls -lG'
export LSCOLORS="ExGxBxDxCxEgEdxbxgxcxd"
export GREP_OPTIONS="--color"

# Erase duplicates in history
export HISTCONTROL=erasedups
# Store 10k history entries
export HISTSIZE=10000
# Append to the history file when exiting instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend

function minutes_since_last_commit {
    now=`date +%s`
    last_commit=`git log --pretty=format:'%at' -1`
    seconds_since_last_commit=$((now-last_commit))
    minutes_since_last_commit=$((seconds_since_last_commit/60))
    echo $minutes_since_last_commit
}
grb_git_prompt() {
    local g="$(__gitdir)"
    if [ -n "$g" ]; then
        local MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT=`minutes_since_last_commit`
        if [ "$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT" -gt 30 ]; then
            local COLOR=${RED}
        elif [ "$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT" -gt 10 ]; then
            local COLOR=${YELLOW}
        else
            local COLOR=${GREEN}
        fi
        local SINCE_LAST_COMMIT="${COLOR}$(minutes_since_last_commit)m${NORMAL}"
        # The __git_ps1 function inserts the current git branch where %s is
        local GIT_PROMPT=`__git_ps1 "(%s|${SINCE_LAST_COMMIT})"`
        echo ${GIT_PROMPT}
    fi
}

export PS1='$(grb_git_prompt)$ '

gd() { git diff $* | view -; }
gdc() { gd --cached $*; }

source ~/bin/git-completion.bash
```

I can confirm the error is in grb_git_promit. What happens is the second lines typed in shell is overwriting the first line. Can anyone could help me with this?

EDIT:

```
grb_git_prompt() {
    local g="$(__gitdir)"
    if [ -n "$g" ]; then
        local MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT=`minutes_since_last_commit`
        if [ "$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT" -gt 30 ]; then
            local COLOR="\[\033[0;31m\]"
        elif [ "$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT" -gt 10 ]; then
            local COLOR="\[\033[0;37m\]"
        else
            local COLOR="\[\033[0;32m\]"
        fi
        local SINCE_LAST_COMMIT="${COLOR}$(minutes_since_last_commit)m$"
        # The __git_ps1 function inserts the current git branch where %s is
    echo "$(__git_ps1 '(%s|')${SINCE_LAST_COMMIT}"
    fi
}
```

Comment: I don't completely understand the problem, but I tested this and it is working fine for me.

Comment: When I type a long command say "gedit /really/long/filename/that/takes/up/two/lines/in/bash/shell" it becomes "bash shell ally/long/filename/that/takes/up/two/lines/in." I'm not sure if I'm explaining it properly, basically when the command becomes two lines, instead of going to second line, it begins to eat up the first line. If you google "bash line wrapping overwrites beginning of line" you'll know what I'm talking about. (I did, but couldn't find any answers.)

Comment: @Senthil: Where do `RED`, `YELLOW`, `GREEN`, and `NORMAL` come from? I bet your problem is in there, since those are presumably terminal escape sequences. If they're being automatically generated somehow, check to make sure that `TERM` has an appropriate value. Also, I suspect that you might want to quote them when assigning: `COLOR="${RED}"`. You could of course confirm whether or not this is the problem by removing the color from the prompt.

Comment: Not sure actually, I copied that part from the original .bashrc file and pasted it here. I edit to include the entire file, if that helps.

Comment: Okay, additionally, hard-coding a value for TERM is really suspicious. That could cause the wrong escape sequences to be generated. What terminal are you actually using? Maybe you should be setting `TERM` to `xterm`, not `xterm-color`?

Comment: Just the vanilla that comes with Ubuntu 10.10. Tried xterm, added quotes to COLOR, unfortunately nothing.

Comment: Good call adding in more of the bashrc: we don't need the whole file, really, but you've now included two obvious places to look: your hard-coding of `TERM`, and the script you source to get color variable definitions. The problem's pretty definitely in there. And see my updated answer!

Comment: I added in the file where the colors were defined, changed TERM (also deleted that entire block) like you suggested, no change.

Comment: @Senthil: Ah, your colors script is hard-coded, never mind. I figured it was automatically detecting things based on the terminal.

Comment: @Jefromi Yea I don't know what's happening, I was watching a peepcode screencast and liked the "
time since last git commit" function and the bashrc files were linked so I decided to try it out.

Comment: @Senthil: Can you narrow it down a bit more by deleting bits and pieces of the prompt function? In particular, does it go away if you remove `${COLOR}` and `${NORMAL}`? Also, you should be quoting `GIT_PROMPT` when you echo it, though you might try shortening those two lines down to: `echo "$(__git_ps1 '(%s|')${SINCE_LAST_COMMIT}"`, so that the escape sequences don't pass through `__git_ps1`.

Comment: The error does go away when I remove those variables, so I guess the error is there. Also added quotes and shortened the two lines.

Comment: @Jefromi With the new echo line, this is what the shell is showing (home|\033[0;31m528m\033[m)$ with the COLOR and NORMAL variables.

Comment: @Senthil: Were you getting color in the prompt before? If you were, then that does mean the escape sequences were getting through... but since they do seem to be causing the problem, there's obviously something wrong with them. I'm off for the night; maybe someone more knowledgeable/awake will happen by!

Comment: I believe so yes. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 27):

When you have colors and other non-printing escape sequences in your prompt, you have to surround them with escaped single brackets. Here is a simple example:

```
PS1='\[\033[38;5;1m\]some red text\[\033[0m\]\$ '
```

Which will cause the prompt to display "some red text" in red and the dollar sign (or "#") in the default color.

Here is another way to do the same thing:

```
red='\033[38;5;1m'
none='\033[0m'
PS1='\[$red\]some red text\[$none\]\$ '
```

By the way, to do this more portably and have less complex build-up of variables:

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
none=$(tput sgr0)
```

See `man 5 terminfo` for more information on the settings.

Comment: I changed the colors and added the single escape brackets (see edit for new function), but all I see is (home|\[\033[0;31m\]541m$

Comment: @Senthil: You need to put the escaped brackets in the assignment to `PS1` rather than in other variables. If you need to set colors in a dynamic prompt then use `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to set `PS1` each time it's issued.

Comment: I decided to change to .zsh and it works flawlessly there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 OMG it works for me with bash, I've had this issue with custom PS1s forever, thanks so much for the fix.